# how to bind each element in form to item in array of objects in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, 2-way-object-databinding

I am trying to bind each element in form to an element in array of objects. What is a good way to do this? Do I need to create client side models and then serialize it? below is jsfiddle on what I am trying to achieve

http://jsfiddle.net/PmChk/1

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
$scope.TestObject = {
"$id" : "1",
"CreatedOn" : null, 
"FieldValues" : [{
        "$id" : "2",
        "FieldId" : "a1",
        "FieldName" : "FirstName",
        "FieldValue" : "Tom",           
    }, {
        "$id" : "3",
        "FieldId" : "a2",
        "FieldName" : "LastName",
        "FieldValue" : "silver",

    }
]
}    
});

<form class="form-horizontal">
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">   
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName" class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
       <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control"/>
       </div>
  </div>                            
  <div class="form-group">
       <label for="lastName" class="col-md-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
       <div class="col-md-8">
       <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control"/>
 </div>         
 </div>
 <form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), and iterate through each item in the array:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">  
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in TestObject.FieldValues">
       <label for="lastName" class="col-md-4 control-label">{{field.FieldName}}</label>
       <div class="col-md-8">
       <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="field.FieldValue"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PmChk/2/)

This will give you an element for every item in the array, bounded to the corresponding values.

Comment: problem with this is it relies on order of fields in array

Comment: Not a problem, you can order them. See [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)